# `error: assignment to expression with array type` when trying to set struct member

Tags: c, syntactic-sugar

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find it.

Consider:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Image {
    char* name;
    float transform[6];
};

int main() {
    float transform[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
    struct Image *ex = calloc(1,sizeof(struct Image));
    ex->name="test";
    // ex->transform=transform; // causes error.
    return 0;
}
```

I of course receive:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:12:18: error: assignment to expression with array type
   12 |     ex->transform=transform;
```

So my question is, is there a more sugary way to do:

```
12c12,17
<     ex->transform=transform; // causes error.
---
>     ex->transform[0]=transform[0];
>     ex->transform[1]=transform[1];
>     ex->transform[2]=transform[2];
>     ex->transform[3]=transform[3];
>     ex->transform[4]=transform[4];
>     ex->transform[5]=transform[5];
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can define a `struct` type containing just the array and use that type in an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can use `memcpy` (declared in `<string.h>`) to copy an array:

```
float transform[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
struct Image *ex = calloc(1, sizeof *ex);
ex->name = "test";
memcpy(ex->transform, transform, sizeof ex->transform);
```

another option is to use a compound literal to assign the complete structure:

```
struct Image *ex = calloc(1, sizeof *ex);
*ex = (struct Image) { "test", { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
```

Of course, there is no need to assign zero elements to the array as it was already set to zero by `calloc`, but you could use the above with other values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memcpy()` function present in `<string.h>` header file.

```
int main()
{
    float transform[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

    struct Image *ex = calloc(1,sizeof(struct Image));
    ex->name="test";

    memcpy(ex->transform ,transform , sizeof(ex->transform));
    free(ex);
    return 0;
}
```